# Getting the next 10th of a month from now?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to find the next 10th of a month starting with today. So if today is the 27th of May, the next 10th is the 10th of June. If today is the 1st of August, the next 10th will be the 10th of August for example.

I know I can find the first day of the next month using

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

Can I use that format for my case as well? If not, how could I achieve my goal?

Thanks a lot for helping! :)

Comment: is it okey with javascript?

Comment: No, I need it for PHP, but thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`strtotime` is not able to do this in one call, but you could do something like:

```
<?php
    $current_day = (int)date('j');

    if ($current_day < 10) {
        $firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days', strtotime('first day of this month')));
    } else {
        $firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days', strtotime('first day of next month')));
    }

    echo $firstDayNextMonth;
?>
```

Or simply just

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days', strtotime('first day of ' . ((int)date('j') < 10 ? 'this' : 'next' ) . ' month')));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I'm using your second code. But, what if I need to put that inside 'for'. Let say I have 5 in $i, so I need value 10June, 10July, 10August, 10Sep, 10Oct ... Please help ...

Comment: How about 
`for($i = 6; $i < 11; $i++) { echo (new DateTime(date('Y') . "-{$i}-01"))->format('Y-m-d') . "\r\n"; }`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$Date = new DateTime('first day of '.(date('j') < 10 ? 'this' : 'next').' month');
$Date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('9 days'));
var_dump($Date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

This will result in '2015-07-10' if it's '2015-06-10' today. Just use `<=` (or `< 11`) if it should return '2015-06-10' in that case.

Comment: What if the next 10th is in the same month? But Iguess I could still use your code, I just have to add or subtract.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `strtotime` is able to do that.

A little trick can be:

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m', strtotime('next month')) . '-10';
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help a bit?

By using mktime you can simply define the day you want, even match more day sin a row more easely.

```
// set our day number
$daynum = 10;
$curDay = date('d');
// get current month
$curMonth = date('n');
// get current year
$curYear  = date('Y');
$firstDayNextMonth = 'MissingNo';
if($curDay < $dayNum) {
     $firstDayNextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $curMonth, $daynum);
}
else {
   // darnit, new year. but will we party?
   if ($curMonth == 12) {
      // use mktime to get a timestamp. We can become very precise with this...
      $firstDayNextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $daynum, $curYear+1);
   }
   else {
       $firstDayNextMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $curMonth+1, $daynum);
       // let's test if we can have a little party or not.
     }
  }
  echo date('D',$firstDayNextMonth) === date('D') ? 'matches! let\'s party!' : 'no match :( hide the beer';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
echo $firstDayNextMonth ."</br>";
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m', strtotime('next month'));
echo $firstDayNextMonth."-10";
```

Is that what you want??

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days', strtotime('first day of this month', strtotime(sprintf('+%d days', (int) date('t') - 10)))));
```