# Getting the next 10th of a month from now using PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, date

I already asked a similar that question here:

[Getting the next 10th of a month from now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474821/getting-the-next-10th-of-a-month-from-now)

The solution there was:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+10 days', strtotime('first day of ' . ((int)date('j') < 10 ? 'this' : 'next' ) . ' month')));
```

But the solution I accepted only works in PHP 5.3+ (because of the "first day of"). I need a solution for PHP 5.2. How could I solve that in PHP 5.2?

Thanks!

Note: I can not update the PHP version :).

Comment: Can't you just update PHP version so you can take advantages of modern technology?

Comment: Nope, I have to use 5.2

Comment: I advice you to update php version, there is many performance improvements after 5.2 version

Comment: Also 5.2 reached end of life neither 5.3

Comment: check: http://php.net/eol.php (eol: end of life)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with -

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(' + 1 month', strtotime(date('Y-m-10'))));
```

**Update**

```
if(strtotime(date('Y-m-10 00:00:00')) < time())
    echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(' + 1 month', strtotime(date('Y-m-10'))));
else
    echo date('10-m-Y');
```

Comment: On `2015-08-01` this code will return `2015-09-10` instead of `2015-08-10`, right? OP does not copied full explanation from previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
// Check if you need next or current month
$month = date('d') < 10 ? date('m') : date('m') + 1;

// mktime will fix 13th month issue converting it to next ears first month
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10, date('Y'));

$date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: You probably mean `$month = ... date('m') + 1;`

Comment: @axiac yes, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try mktime()

$month = (int)date('j') < 10 ? date('n') : date('n')+1;

echo date('d.m.Y', mktime(0,0,0,$month,date('j')+15,date('Y')))