# Getting the next 10th of a month from now inside a loop

Tags: php, loops, date

Actually I'm reading this thread : [Getting the next 10th of a month from now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474821/getting-the-next-10th-of-a-month-from-now), but I need more explanation. What if I need to put that inside 'for' / loop. Let say I have 5 in $i, so I need value 10June, 10July, 10August, 10Sep, 10Oct ...
Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved ...

```
    $theDue = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days', strtotime('first day of ' . ((int)date('j') < 10 ? 'this' : 'next' ) . ' month'))) ;
    for ($i=0; $i < $numPay ; $i++) { 
      $newDue = (date("Y-m-d", strtotime(+$i." month", strtotime($theDue)))) ;
      print_r($newDue);echo('<br/>');
    }
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).